# How can i print random task/item from the list in flutter? - Instead showing content of list it just prints "instance of "task"?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, math, random

I was wondering how can I print/display text of random item from the list?
Here is the code of the list i have

```
class TaskData extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Task> _tasks = [
    Task(name: "Task one"),
    Task(name: "Task two"),
    Task(name: "Task three"),
  ];

  UnmodifiableListView<Task> get tasks {
    return UnmodifiableListView(_tasks);
  }

  int get taskCount {
    return _tasks.length;
  }

  void randomvo() {
    var randomItem = (_tasks.toList()..shuffle()).first;
    print(randomItem);
  }
```

Here I have a different file with buttons and I managed to get some code to just test it out, but instead of printing random names from the list(Like task one or task two), it just prints "Instance of "Task""

```
return Scaffold(
  floatingActionButton: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    children: <Widget>[
      FloatingActionButton.extended(
          label: const Text("Randomize"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          onPressed: () {
            Provider.of<TaskData>(context, listen: false).randomvo();
          }),
```

Would really appreciate it if someone could help me with this one
Thank you!

Comment: Are you certain your random code doesn't work? It should. Is there a chance you just got really unlucky and displayed the second item several times? After running your code 1000 times on dartpad, first item appears 313 times, second item 350 and third item 337.

Comment: Hi I actually change my code to this one now and it seems to be working, when I put the var randomitem inside the on pressed, when I put it outside it just kept saying same item`    var list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          FloatingActionButton.extended(
              onPressed: () {
                var randomItem = (list.toList()..shuffle()).first;
                print(randomItem);
                //print(randomString);
              }),`

Comment: Do you know maybe how could i make it work from my other script file of _tasks list?

Comment: ok, it seems your problem was you wanted a different number for every button press, while the code you posted was designed to show a different random value every time you loaded the app. Happy you figured it out :)

Comment: Hi, yes I have finally managed to work it out, but this one seems to be more difficult for me. Do you know maybe why instead of printing the actual content of my Task, it just prints "Instance of "task" ?

Comment: dart doesn't know what to print, you need to either print some info about your task (like `print(task.title);`) or override the toString method on your class Task like so: `toString() { return 'this will be printed to the console when calling print(task);';`}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I can't believe i actually got it right and it works :O After hours of playing around with code, googling finally made it work!!
I wrote this in my one script file with the list.

```
  void randomvo(String) {
    var randomItem = (_tasks.toList()..shuffle()).first.name;
    print(randomItem);
  }
```

Then on the press button I wrote this

```
onPressed: () {
            Provider.of<TaskData>(context, listen: false).randomvo(String);
          }
```

Works !!!
Hope that helps someone who runs into something similar

Answer (score 0):

Modify your task class like this

```
class Task{
    String ? name;
    Task({this.name});
    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name,
      };
  }
```

Use this in randomvo

print(jsonEncode(randomItem.toJson()));